# Redirecting non "www" to "www" and rewrite all subdomains except www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to have all domain.com on my website to redirect to www.domain.com

and

all subdomains that are not www.domain.com such as xyz.domain.com/abc rewritten (not a redirect as it will still show xyz.domain.com/abc on the browser) to www.domain.com/page.php?id=xyz&param=abc.

Currently I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?[^.]+\.domain\.com.*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/hosted_form.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It successfully redirects domain.com to www.domain.com but displays server not found for mno.domain.com/efg.

Comment: Are these sites on the same server? Do you have DNS records setup for all your subdomains you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Addition to Saddam Abu Ghaida Solution, which fixes your problem with non-www urls, You have to To enable wildcard subdomains to avoid the "server not found" problem for any subdomain.

If you are using Apache, Modify your httpd.conf configuration file to include the Wildcard line as following:

```
NameVirtualHost ?.?.?.?

<VirtualHost ?.?.?.?>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias *.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I followed your comment and enabled the wildcard subdomains but @Saddam solution redirects all subdomains to www.domain.com; whereas I only want domain.com to be redirected to www.domain.com and other subdomains not redirected but rewritten to another URL.

Comment: Ok, The first step, which is reaching the site through the subdomain is done then. Now you have to decide the redirection target basing on the requested subdomain just aas following:
<pre>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.site.local$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sub.site.local$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://<destination url>/$1 [L]
</pre>

Comment: To be clear:

-RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.site.local$ [OR]
-RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sub.site.local$
-RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://<destination url>/$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?domain.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]  
RewriteRule .? http://www.%domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It successfully redirects non- www to www (had to remove the first % on the rewriterule),  but when i use demo.domain.com, gives me server not found.

Comment: in your example you are rewriting the query string from subdomains isn't it. and this is what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to 1. if there is no subdomain eg. domain.com, it redirects to www.domain.com; but when there is a subdomain that is not www eg. sub.domain.com/abc, it doesn't redirect but rewrites to domain.com/id=sub&param=abc.